# Toolbar not showing with Navigation Drawer. Not in the android studio nor in the device

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I'm using a Navigation Drawer in my app. I want to add a toolbar in it but the toolbar is not showing. it just gives the size estimation the design preview. As shown in the picture

[image]

I have tried almost everything I could but it's not working.
 Thanks in advance :)

xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.mrvirk.urduapp.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            />




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="8">


        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout


            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:columnCount="2"
            app:rowCount="4">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/green3"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/learning"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/learning"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtLearning"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/i_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/yellow"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/acheivements"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/acheivements"

                    />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtAcheivements"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/i_national"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                app:layout_columnSpan="2"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/quiz"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/quiz" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtQuiz"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Quiz"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/blue2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/setting"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/setting" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSetting"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Setting"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/tea"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/share"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/share" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtshare"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Share"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/org"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/about"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/about" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtAbout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="About"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/green3"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/moreApps"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/moreapps" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtMoreApps"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="More Apps"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Toolbar in main activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.done);
```

Menifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mrvirk.urduapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name="com.example.mrvirk.urduapp.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What theme are you using in your style?

Comment: just put the toolbar view at the bottom in frame layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include layout="@layout/layout_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/include_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> include_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/light_black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        />



    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:rowCount="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/green3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/learning"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/learning"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLearning"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/i_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/yellow"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/acheivements"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/acheivements"

                />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAcheivements"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/i_national"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            app:layout_columnSpan="2"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/quiz"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/quiz" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtQuiz"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Quiz"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/blue2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/setting"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/setting" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSetting"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Setting"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/tea"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/share" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtshare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Share"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/org"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/about" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAbout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="About"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/green3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/moreApps"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/moreapps" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMoreApps"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="More Apps"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to replace the `FrameLayout` and use a `RelativeLayout` instead. Indeed, the `RelativeLayout` should contain `Toolbar` and the `LinearLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:weightSum="8">
 ....
</LinearLayout>
```

The fact that the `LinearLayout` is drawn below the toolbar is enforced by this:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` or `CoordinateLayout`

if you use `LinearLayout` then,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        />
    ........
</LinearLayout>
```

or if you use `CoordinateLayout` then,

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:weightSum="8">
    .......
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android draws Views from top to down so; A-B-C- are you 3 respective Views in your DrawerLayout. now A being the Toolbar is drawn first with params width fit-to-the-overallwidth and height fit the content itself, B is drawn with width fit-to-the-overallwidth and height fit-to-the-overallheight, etc etc. that means your FrameLayout is drawn second in the drawing successions and on top of your Toolbar but since its covered you do not see that it is there, if you bring it below, your Toolbar is drawn second in succession hence you see it.

Credits : @Elltz

So just put your toolbar at end of the Frame layout.
I modified your code try this and let me know now toolbar is displaying or not :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout

        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="8">


            <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout


                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:columnCount="2"
                app:rowCount="4">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/green3"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/learning"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/learning"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtLearning"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/i_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/yellow"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/acheivements"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/acheivements"

                        />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtAcheivements"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/i_national"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/red"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/quiz"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/quiz" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtQuiz"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Quiz"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/blue2"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/setting"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/setting" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtSetting"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Setting"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/tea"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/share"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/share" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtshare"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Share"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/org"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/about"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/about" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtAbout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="About"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/green3"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/moreApps"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/moreapps" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtMoreApps"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="More Apps"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            />


    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is resolved but the toolbar is showing over the grid item (over first tiles). the above answer resolved all the problem. Thanks for your help too :)

Answer (score 0):

main layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size300"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_background_selector"
    app:itemTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

app_bar_main layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.appsdevelopment.stylus.aci.allor_shathi.activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_minus45"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```